# How to trigger Animation on one Item in a ListView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I try to trigger a `SequentialAnimation` on a given `Item` of a `ListView`.

For example:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListModel {
        id: modelList
        ListElement {}
        ListElement {}
        ListElement {}
    }

    ListView {
        width: window.width
        height: window.height

        model: modelList
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: window.width
            height: window.height/10
            color: "red"
            radius : 10
            SequentialAnimation on color { //Should be only triggered when button clicked
                ColorAnimation { to: "yellow"; duration: 1000 }
                ColorAnimation { to: "red"; duration: 1000 }
            }

            Button {
                text: "trigger animation"
                anchors{
                    right: parent.right
                    top: parent.top
                    bottom: parent.bottom
                    margins: 10
                }

                onClicked: {
                    //Trigger SequentialAnimation
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to trigger the `Animation` **when you click on the button** but I don't know how to use a `condition` on an `Animation`. 
How could I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use animation `on property` only if you want changes to be automatically animated.

In your case you need to remove the `on color` part, then give the animation an `id: yourAnimation`, and on the button click `yourAnimation.start()`

Actually, it seems that `on color` is also possible, skipping setting the target:

```
SequentialAnimation on color {
  id: yourAnimation
  ColorAnimation { to: "yellow"; duration: 1000 }
  ColorAnimation { to: "red"; duration: 1000 }
  running: false
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works ! 
I also have to add `target: myItem; property: "color";`  in `ColorAnimation`

Comment: @dtech Could you please help me with the following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918657/how-to-smoothly-load-lines-with-customized-scrollbar-event-in-qt

Comment: @dtech Any help would be deeply appreciated.